# How do I complete the achievement 'Ling-Ting's Herbal Journey'?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

How do I complete the achievement 'Ling-Ting's Herbal Journey'?

> **Ling-Ting's Herbal Journey**
>
> Collect all 30 Golden Hoplings hidden around the Stormstout Brewery on any difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to even see the Golden Hoplings, you must speak to Auntie Stormstout just inside the instance entrance to the Stormstout Brewery and purchase 'Ling-Ting's Favourite Tea';

[image: Auntie Stormstout] 
[image: Tea]

You can get as much of this tea as you need, there is no limit on it.

Once you have used the item, the Golden Hoplings have nameplates which have a high visibility and hunters can track them;

[image: Hopling]

There are a total of thirty Hoplings in the instance, so just keep going until the achievement pops up.

Comment: Which mod did you use to change the font?

Comment: I didn't - create a folder in your WoW folder called 'Fonts' and then copy a TTF for the font you wish to use into there *twice* and rename the files to ARIALN.ttf and FRIZQT__.ttf - WoW will use these fonts over the equivalent files with the same names stored in the MPQs on runtime.